# How to programm an interaction between the navigation and the content

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

My problem:
I have an index.html and I have (for now) two servlets. One is generating a navigation by loading the categories out of the DB, and the other one is getting the articles of the navigation and putting it in the content space to the right of the navigation. The problem is, that I have no clue how these two servlets are surposed to work together. When I click on a button of my navigation, the content space is loading as a single page, or not loading at all.

**First**, loading as a single page:

in my index.html, I have the following jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                        
        $('#navigation').load('Navigation');
        $('#content').load('Content');
    });
```

These are my two servlets I am loading into their divs in this index file.

This is one category link of my navigation servlet:

```
out.println("<li><a><form action='Content' method='get'><button type='submit'>" + k2.getKName() + "</button><input type='hidden' name='category' value='"+ k2.getKategorieNr() + "'/></form></a></li>");
```

When I do it on that way, the content is loading as a new page and not inside the content space.

My **second** idea would be deleting the action='Content' and try to implement the communication between the servlets in a different way.

I am adding a dispatcher to my navigation like that:

```
request.setAttribute("cat" ,request.getParameter("category"));
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Content"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

and an id='cat' to my form above. But now the navigation isn't loading at all anymore.

I would like to use the first idea, but I don't know how I can load the content inside the index. I tried different plugins but it didn't work.

Does anyone have a completly different approach where this would be much easier to solve? Like with a controller or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {                        
$('#navigation').load('Navigation');
$('#content').load('Content?page=1');
});

$(document).on("click","a",function(){
    $('#content').load('Content?page='+$(this).attr('data-selectedpage'));
    return 0;
});


</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
This is the loaded content
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Content.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Content
 */
@WebServlet("/Content")
public class Content extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getOutputStream().println("Page: "+request.getParameter("page"));

    }

}
```

Navigation.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Navigation
 */
@WebServlet("/Navigation")
public class Navigation extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter wtr=  response.getWriter();
        wtr.println("<nav>");
        wtr.println("<a href='#'  data-selectedpage='1'>Page 1</a><br/>");
        wtr.println("<a href='#'  data-selectedpage='2'>Page 2</a><br/>");
        wtr.println("<a href='#'  data-selectedpage='3'>Page 3</a><br/>");
        wtr.println("</nav");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. The only thing I see is "This is the loaded content "

Comment: Works for me, you need to make sure Content and Navigation java classes are also copied into your webapp (default package),   Are you running it on a tomcat 7 server ??

Comment: The war file (included sourcecode) can be downloaded here: https://www.tonyweston.co.uk/FriendlyStock_splits/gifts/StackOverflow.war

Comment: How can I do this with a search form? Is this the same concept?

Comment: I think so - you would just include the search query at the end of the post URL  -   post('Content?search='+search);

Comment: But isn't there an extra method for submit?